# Open databases representing a tree

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for open databases representing a tree data structure. I've already found the animal taxonomy, which is a perfect use case, but I'm looking for further open databases, focusing on a topic of commercial and/or scientific interest. I've found several databases representing a directed graph, but I have difficulty at finding databases representing a tree.

Answer (score 1):

Check Wikipedia Category Tree

https://www.kaggle.com/kevinlu1248/wikipedia-category-tree

Wikidata Taxonomy. There is an hierarchy of "Instance of" P31 properties for each entity defined in Wikidata

https://www.npmjs.com/package/wikidata-taxonomy

Comment: This is actually a DAG, but perhaps I'll be able to use it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database#List_of_graph_databases) you can see both proprietary and open source graph database. The open source graph databases: Neo4j, RedisGraph, TerminusDB, JanusGraph, Grakn Core.</strike>

On the website of Apache project [TinkerPop](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/#graph-systems), you can also see a longer list of graph databases (both open source and proprietary) it supports.

Comment: What you suggest are DBMS, while I'm looking for databases.